# What is the command equivalent to GeneXus 9 "Force Theme" in Genexus X?

Tags: themes, genexus

I need to force a GeneXus Theme in my application, changing controls classes to default names in some imported objects (webpanels and transactions).
In Genexus 9 there is a **"Force Theme**" command. I can't find something similar in Genexus X.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enrique, it's a missing feature, afaik there are no plans to implement it right now, though it has been already suggested by others too. See [here](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxppredirect.aspx?15,26,0,,,23758)